# Neovim/Spacevim - Display Function/Method Name Cursor is Located in

Tags: neovim, spacevim

I recently switched to using Neovim/Spacevim, and it's freakin' awesome! I have been trying to change some settings and install plugins to emulate as close as possible to my previous VSCode development environment.

I'm nearly there, except the only thing missing is one feature I really loved. In any file, wherever my cursor was located, at the top of the status bar in VSCode, it would display the function/method (*or variable, object, etc.*) name.

Does anyone know if this is possible in Neovim/Spacevim. If my cursor is located within a function named `someFunction`, how would I get `someFunction` to be displayed somewhere in the status bar? I am using the standard `statusline` bar, no plugins for that (*though am willing to install one if it does what I need*).